# Bootstrap table row click to open up additional options buttons

Tags: html, css, angularjs, html-table

We have a table that we've created using angularjs and want to add an option for each row to either Edit or Delete.  We really want something that resembles this [codepen](https://codepen.io/brody/pen/rwEVKZ), but without jquery.

So far we have the following:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in data.list | filter:searchTable track by item.sys_id" >
    <td class="moreOption">
      <div class="more" ng-click="c.showHide(item);">
        <div class='moredrop' ng-hide="!item.IsHidden">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <i class='material-icons'>edit</i>
              <span class='label'>Edit</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <i class='material-icons'>delete</i>
              <span class='label'>Delete</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </td>
  </tr>
```

In our client controller, we have:

```
c.showHide = function(item) {
  item.IsHidden = !item.IsHidden;
}
```

What we're really struggling with is the CSS styling of the pop-up box that shows Edit or Delete.  We want it to "float" next to the 3 vertical dots icon when clicked on, much like the codepen link above, but can't seem to get it to look like that.  Additionally, right now when you click the 3 vertical dots for one row, then click another row, it opens up 2 boxes.  What do we have to do in our client controller for one click to close the previous pop up box?

Comment: You want them to actually have to click to expose the extra options and track the visible bool per row so they can keep it visible or not on multiple rows at a time? Or would you rather just expose it in a nifty way on hover of the row like that codepen and keep it on the compositor thread (personal suggestion) with just css instead of adding more watchers and another property per item that will inevitably give performance issues the more rows you add?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a simple Bootstrap dropdown?

[Dropdowns: Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/)

Use your own button or icon to launch the dropdown with this code.

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```